# Error en un servicio de hace un quequest, NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpServiceService

Tags: http, angular

Según eh estado leyendo por el error que me da es por que me falta algún import en el module de la app ,pero no veo que falte ninguno,tengo el servicio y el componente desde donde llamo al servicio y el module de la app en distintas carpetas,eso no influye no?

El module de la app:

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WelcomerSelectHotelComponent } from './components/welcomer-select-hotel/welcomer-select-hotel.component';
import { AppRoutesModule } from './app-routes.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomerSelectHotelComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutesModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Este es mi servicio

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


    @Injectable()
    export class HttpServiceService {


      private ROOT_URL = 'https://...............';

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

      getPosts() {
        return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}`);
      }


    }
```

el error que me da es algo asi:

> ERROR  Error columnNumber: 31 fileName:
>   "http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js line 597 > eval"
>   lineNumber: 814 message: "Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[WelcomerSelectHotelComponent ->
>   HttpServiceService]: \n  StaticInjectorError(Platform:
>   core)[WelcomerSelectHotelComponent -> HttpServiceService]: \n
>   NullInjectorError: No provider for
>   HttpServiceService!\n_NullInjector.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1219:19\nresolveToken@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1517:17\ntryResolveToken@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1459:16\nStaticInjector.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1327:20\nresolveToken@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1517:17\ntryResolveToken@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1459:16\nStaticInjector.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1327:20\nresolveNgModuleDep@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:11112:12\nNgModuleRe…"
>   promise: Object { **zone_symbol__state: 0, __zone_symbol__value: Error
>   } rejection: Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[WelcomerSelectHotelComponent ->
>   HttpServiceService]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform:
>   core)[WelcomerSelectHotelComponent -> HttpServiceService]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpServiceService! Stack trace: [object Object] stack:
>   "resolvePromise@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:814:31\nresolvePromise@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:771:17\nscheduleResolveOrReject/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:873:17\nZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:17\nonInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:4967:24\nZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:420:17\nZone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:28\ndrainMicroTaskQueue@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:595:25\nZoneTask.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:500:21\ninvokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540:9\nglobalZoneAwareCallback@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1566:17\n"
>   task: Object { runCount: 0, _state: "notScheduled", type: "microTask",
>   … } zone: Object { _properties: {…}, _parent: {…}, _name: "angular", …
>   }
>   __proto**: Object { … }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas importar `HttpClientModule` en el servicio, solo `HttpClient`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable()
export class HttpServiceService {


  private ROOT_URL = 'https://...............';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPosts() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}`);
  }


}
```

Ademas necesitas incluir el servicio en providers dentro del decorador @NgModule en tu `AppModule`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpServiceService } from /* Aqui pones donde se ubica el servicio */
import { WelcomerSelectHotelComponent } from './components/welcomer-select-hotel/welcomer-select-hotel.component';
import { AppRoutesModule } from './app-routes.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomerSelectHotelComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutesModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [HttpServiceService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Recuerda poner la ruta de donde se encuentra el servicio.

Comment: hola amigo, tengo un problema similar pero usando el cdk de angular para trabajar con breakpoints, podrías echarme una mano ?